# Update Listbox with item on navigation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When I navigate from a page to another I am passing an object of class and adding to list view. But the problem I am facing is that each time when the page is navigated the item is added in list box but the item that was previously added gets removed.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue and how I can retrieve the previous listbox item?

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if ((App.Current as App).isThereAnyChange)
    {
        getitem();
        changeUI();
    } 
}

private void changeUI()
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    txt1.Text = "";
    items.Add(item1);
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            this.sniplist.ItemsSource = items;
        });
}

private void getitem()
{
    //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    item1 = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["item"] as Item;
    // Debug.WriteLine(item1.description);
}
```

Comment: Is the items collection a member of the page? if so, then each time a new instance of the page is created, then you will have a new collections created...

Comment: @Jogy Yes items is ObservableCollection which is part of page.

Comment: A better design would be to make a separate class that holds the ObservableCollection, and instantiate that class once, for example in App.xaml.cs.

Comment: @Jogy Can you please explain with some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a static item in your ....xaml.cs file

```
static List<object> listSrc = new List<object>();

override OnNavigatedTo()
{
   listSrc.Add("whatever you want");
   sniplist.ItemsSource= listSrc;
}
```

Comment: Yes but I want to change UI also from textblock to Listview when the item is added for the first time.

Comment: Will this increment the count of List items each time the OnNavigatedTo method is called?

Comment: Thanx @Kowalski It solved my issue but now problem is that when I remove item using ContextMenu the item gets removed. But in list if there is only one item then the item doesn't gets removed. Please do reply.

Comment: I couldn't understand your question but why don't you remove item `listSrc` when removing ListItem ? Or just keep another static list which Items are removed ones. And always control it to adding item in 'listSrc' if item removed before.

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple setup:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; private set; }

  public MainViewModel() { Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(); }
}
```

in App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
  private static MainViewModel viewModel = new MainViewModel();
  public static MainViewModel ViewModel { get { return viewModel; } }
  ...
```

And then you can access that class from any page simply with App.ViewModel, and it will persist through page navigations.

Comment: Thanks @Jogy I will try to implement this and come back to you if it solves my case.